# Access to private properties of a child class

Tags: php, oop

I've been trying to understand how class scope affects access to private and protected properties of different objects. And found something strange when i try to access private properties of a child class in the context of its parent.

Here is the code example. You can see the very same behavior if you replace methods with properties.

```
class ParentClass{
    public function test($childObj){
        $childObj->getProtected();
        $childObj::getProtected();
        $childObj->getPrivate();
        $childObj::getPrivate();
    }
    private function getPrivate(){
        echo "ParentClass private";
    }
    protected function getProtected(){
        echo "ParentClass protected";
    }
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    private function getPrivate(){
        echo "ChildClass private";
    }
    protected function getProtected(){
        echo "ChildClass protected";
    }
}
(new ParentClass)->test(new ChildClass());
```

The outputs:

```
ChildClass protected
ChildClass protected (and E_DEPRICATED error)
ParentClass private
Fatal error: Call to private ChildClass::getPrivate() from context 'ParentClass'
```

Well, im fine with the first two outputs. I think it is mentioned somewhere in docs, that in parent context I can access protected methods/properties of a child class. But what about private? Why does it fall back to ParentClass method in 3rd output, and throws an error in 4th?

Comment: Are you deliberately trying to break inheritence by using one class instance to access the values of another class instance? This doesn't seem very realistic for real world coding

Comment: why you are calling non static method of class with scope resolution `::` operator.

Comment: Mark Baker, Okay, i think you are right. I dont actually know what im trying to do, i was reading some book about OOP. And, thats my way, when i read something i always ask myself "But how would it behaves if i do like so" :/

Comment: Kamran, Just because it is allowed. Im not using $this variable in method so i can do it. Shouldn't it be the same outcome ?

Comment: Well a quirk of PHP OOP is that other instances of a class have access to each other's privates, but it's not a situation that you'd normally ever encounter in real world programming, but your'e also trying to access instance/non-static methods statically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an interesting question, so I dug into a small research. Actually some of the calls you make behave according to the documentation, but some others are rare in the real life and not documented, so we can treat them as a PHP implementation detail.

First, you should not use the `::` operator on the non-static methods, as the PHP notification states, this is deprecated behavior.

So let's split your test into two separate tests - one for non-static methods and another one for static methods.
Here is non-static methods test:

```
class ParentClass{
    public function test($childObj){
        $childObj->getProtected();
        $childObj->getPrivate();
    }
    private function getPrivate(){
        echo "ParentClass private";
    }
    protected function getProtected(){
        echo "ParentClass protected";
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    private function getPrivate(){
        echo "ChildClass private";
    }
    protected function getProtected(){
        echo "ChildClass protected";
    }
}

(new ParentClass)->test(new ChildClass());
```

It outputs:

> ChildClass protected
>
> ParentClass private

And here is the relevant part from the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and protected members even though they are not the same instances. This is because the implementation specific details are already known when inside those objects.

In the frist case, `$childObj->getProtected();` - it works, as the `$childObj` is a sub-type of the `ParentClass`, so it can be treated as an object of the same type.
So here we are:

1. Treating the `$childObj` variable as being of the `ParentClass` type
2. Calling the `getProtected()` method
3. This method is protected, so inheritance rules are applied and we call the child class implementation
4. We get the "ChildClass protected" output

When we try to do the same thing with the private method, we are still allowed to call `$childObj->getPrivate()`, but in this case inheritance rules are not applied, as the private members / methods can not be used through the inheritance. So at this point we are:

1. Treating the `$childObj` variable as being ParentClass type
2. Calling the `getPrivate()` method
3. Since it is private, inheritance rules are not applied (although, this the language implementation detail, see below) and we call the ParentClass implementation
4. We get the "ParentClass private" output

Now, for the static method method we are calling the class-level method, not the instance-level, so no inheritance rules are applicable here.

I think, it is clearer if we write the code for the static calls this way (we don't really need the object instance, we only need a class name):

```
class ParentClass{
    public static function test() {
        ChildClass::getProtected();
        ChildClass::getPrivate();
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    private static function getPrivate(){
        echo "ChildClass private";
    }
    protected static function getProtected(){
        echo "ChildClass protected";
    }
}
(new ParentClass)->test();
```

It outputs:

> ChildClass protected
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to private method ChildClass::getPrivate() from context 'ParentClass'

I think, it's obvious here why the second call raises an error - we are just trying to call the private staic method of another class.

It's more interesting why the first call, `ChildClass::getProtected()`, works, as we are also trying to call a protected method of another class and inheritance rules should not apply here.

The only explanation I can find is that's just an implementation detail of the language.
I think this protected method call shouldn't really work.

I also tried to compare this to C++, here is what I get for [the first test](https://ideone.com/3BKNhM):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ParentClass {
    public:
        void test(ParentClass* obj);
    protected:
        virtual void getProtected();
    private:
        virtual void getPrivate();
};

class ChildClass: public ParentClass{
    protected:
        virtual void getProtected();
    private:
        virtual void getPrivate();
};


//private virtual
void ParentClass::getPrivate(){
    cout << "ParentClass private";
}
//protected virtual
void ParentClass::getProtected(){
    cout << "ParentClass protected";
}
//public
void ParentClass::test(ParentClass* obj) {
    obj->getProtected();
    obj->getPrivate();
};

//private virtual
void ChildClass::getPrivate(){
    cout << "ChildClass private";
}
//protected virtual
void ChildClass::getProtected(){
    cout << "ChildClass protected";
}

int main() {
    cout << "test";
    (new ParentClass)->test(new ChildClass);
}
```

And it outputs:

> test
>
> ChildClass protected
>
> ChildClass private

So it works for the private method differently than in PHP and C++ actually calls the child class implementation even for the private method.

The second test for static methods:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ParentClass {
    public:
        static void test();
};

class ChildClass: public ParentClass{
    protected:
       static void getProtected();
    private:
        static void getPrivate();
};

//public static
void ParentClass::test() {
    // error: 'static void ChildClass::getProtected()' is protected
    //ChildClass::getProtected();
    // error: 'static void ChildClass::getPrivate()' is private
    //ChildClass::getPrivate();
};

//private static
void ChildClass::getPrivate(){
    cout << "ChildClass private";
}
//protected static
void ChildClass::getProtected(){
    cout << "ChildClass protected";
}


int main() {
    cout << "test";
    (new ParentClass)->test();
}
```

Both protected and private calls do not work here. You can't even compile a program with these calls.

This is I think more logical than in PHP where you can call the protected static method.